# Irreducible Polynomial of Galois field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, irreducible-polynomials, cryptography

We know that one irreducible polynomial on $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ is 
$x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$. How to check that it is irreducible?
And how to generate irreducible polynomial for any degree?

Comment: That polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_2$. Not sure about $\Bbb{Z}_{2^8}$ because A) that is not an integral domain, and the definition of irreducibility of a polynomial over a non-integral domain is a bit awkward. B) because you tagged this with [tag:cryptography] I am morally certain that you are looking at AES/Rijndael polynomial. And, therefore are really interested in the field $\Bbb{F}_{2^8}$ also known as $GF(2^8)$ which is a very different object from $\Bbb{Z}_{256}$.

Comment: I am closing this as a dupe, because the only meaningful question here was answered in that thread (possibly also elsewhere, that was the first hit). Note that the polynomial is NOT irreducible over the field $\Bbb{F}_{2^8}$. Rather the opposite! It splits into linear factors over $\Bbb{F}_{2^8}$.

Comment: See [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Rijndael) for appearances of Rijndael on our site. Check [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E8%20%2B%20x%5E4%20%2B%20x%5E3%20%2B%20x%20%2B%201%24&p=1) for other occurrences of this polynomial. If something is still unaswered, edit that into this question and clarify. We can equally easily reopen it!

Comment: Generating irreducible polynomials of a given degree is a bit less taxing than generating prime numbers of a prescribed number of bits. Possible, but there is no easy pencil&paper method. There are also tables of primitive polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_2$ of varying degrees (on-line and in books).

Comment: Anyway, $\Bbb{Z}/256$ is not a Galois field. You are tyring to understand the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1\rangle$. Look up textbooks with titles like *First course in abstract algebra* to learn about the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The polynomial $x^{p^n}-x$ is the product of all monic irreducible polynomials in ${\Bbb F}_p[x]$ whose degree is a divisor of $n$.
In this way, one could iteratively construct irreducible polynomials of larger and larger degree.